# String that contains multiple values

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I'm making a small login form.
The user can login with username: Test, test1, test2, test3

Is it possible to make a string like:

```
string username("test",  "test1", "test2", "test3");
```

And use a code like this:

```
if (usernameTextBox.Text == username)
{
    //Something
}
```

So when the user write in any of the choises i made in the string, he can login.

Comment: Check something about basic data structures, like arrays first

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create collection of strings:

```
string[] names = { "test",  "test1", "test2", "test3" };
```

And check if user name is in this array:

```
if (names.Contains(usernameTextBox.Text))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Array Like:

```
string[] usernames = new string[]{"name2", "name2", "name3"};
```

check array for username

```
foreach (string username in usernames)
{
    if(usernameTextBox.Text == username)
    {
         //do something
    }

}
```